# How can I hide methods in my C# code from documentation?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of classes of the following format, located in the various namespaces. Instances of these classes are serialized and de-serialized objects across the network.

```
public class Foo:INetSerializable
{

    public void ReadObjectData(Streamer stream)
    {

    }

    public void WriteObjectData(Streamer stream)
    {


   }
}
```

In a different namespace, I have a Dispatcher class that uses some criteria to serialize/deserialize these instances.

However, I don't want users to see these methods in my documentation. I cannot make these guys internal because then Dispatcher wouldn't be able to access them.

I use Visual Studio 2005, so I cannot take advantage of C# 3.0.

How can I do this?

---

***Another Error:***

How do I deal with a class that inherits from Foo and overrides the Read and WriteObjectData for example, the following is giving me this error:
**type does not implement interface INetSerializable**

```
public class Bar:Foo
    {

        public void ReadObjectData(Streamer stream)
        {

        }

        public void WriteObjectData(Streamer stream)
        {


       }
    }
```

Comment: When you say the Dispatcher is in a different namespace, is it in the same assembly? Internal means accessible to the assembly, not the namespace.

Comment: It is in the same assembly but in different interface. Isn't internal mean, per-namespace or am I confusing it with Java?

Comment: no, as Steve said internal has assembly scope.  You can also have protected internal. :-)

Comment: Yep, as long as they're in the same assembly then all is good, so you may have seen a problem that isn't there :-) Bear in mind that protected internal means protected OR internal, so can be accessed by anything that is allowed by protected or internal modifiers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explicit interface implementation. I believe the syntax would be

```
void INetSerializable.ReadObjectData(Streamer stream)
```

Note that it doesn't say "public", so it's not public. It can only be  accessed through the interface.

Comment: If someone instantiates the class though through the interface, i.e. INetSerializable obj = new Foo();  these would then be visible to the user wouldn't they?

Comment: Yes, they would - but I suspect most people won't do that. It at least gets them out of the way for normal use. You can't actually stop them from getting called though.

Comment: Right. He said he didn't want users to see the methods, but he wanted his Dispatcher to be able to call them.

Comment: I guess, explicit interface implementation solves the problem. Plus, a client cannot use INetSerializable as  I don't expose it in the API. ..
thx again